# exterior clearcoat for flashings

Tags: painting

Manufacturers of certain metal roofing materials which can be used for flashings and valleys advise clearcoating the metal before exposing it to the acids of certain woods.

I am looking for a clear coating that will adhere to copper and terne coated stainless roof flashings for valleys, chimney crickets, and pipe penetrations.

What kind of exterior clearcoat should this be? Are there exterior paints without pigments which have good adhesion to metal?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a prefinished aluminum (with Kynar finish).  If you can't attain it or already installed the flashing - purchase Parapro - it's a liquid applied membrane that is amazing!

Comment: Thanks for the tip about Papapro, I will keep it in mind, but my question here is really specific.  I need a clear coat.

Comment: You can try this...http://www.elastomericroofcoating.com/